# Changing the Text of a Button in a Table

Tags: javascript, html, button

I haven't been programming in javascript that long and come from a Java background. I am trying to use event handlers in my code and I am running into problems. I have a 3x3 table since I am making a tic tac toe game and when the user clicks on one of the boxes I want to change the button text to an X. So I have the html for my table and buttons are the table data and I have assigned all buttons when clicked to the same function. When a button is clicked I sent its ID to my function and from there I try to use this ID param to set the text but it's just not happening at this point and I'm sort of confused why not. I also did a prompt(paramID) and paramID is correct so I don't understand what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated! It's probably something stupid I did on my part. I've tried firefox and chrome...

Here is my code:

```
<table id="tictable" border="1" 

<tr id="row1">
<td><button id="button1" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button2" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button3" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
</tr>


<tr >
<td><button id="button4" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button5" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button6" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
</tr>


<tr id="row3">
<td><button id="button7" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button8" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
<td><button id="button9" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button></td>
</tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">



function actionPerformed(paramID)
{

    document.getElementById(paramID).value = "X";

}

</script>
```

Comment: you're not closing your opening <button> tag. and you have no text inside your <button> tags.  <button>text here</button>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use .innerHTML.

```
function actionPerformed(paramID)
{
    document.getElementById(paramID).innerHTML = "X";
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cD4Vr/)**

The best way would be to remove all inline javascript and use this

```
window.onload = function () {
    var all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    console.log(all_buttons);
    for (i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
        all_buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function () {
            this.innerHTML = 'X';
        });
    };
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Tpd/1/)**

Comment: I just tried this out and it didn't change the text of the button. I am not sure why though. It does look correct.

Comment: @Tastybrownies, it works on the demo clicking the button. Keep in mind the button has no content so they are small.

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew it was something small like that. My fat fingers and HTML tags are not a good mix. Thank you again. It now works.

Comment: @Tastybrownies, glad I could help! You can click to accept the answer. And, btw, check my 2nd Demo, it is better practice.

Answer (score 1):

What Sergio said, plus for all of your buttons:

```
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"</button>
```

should be:

```
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this.id)"></button>
```

See the missing `>`?

Answer (score 1):

you neglected to close your opening `<table>` and `<button>` tags.  when making the function call just pass `this` in parens and pull the id out in the function.  then update the innards of your button to X.  if you want to swap the  out for a X you will have to access the parentNode and then update the parent's innerHTML

```
<table id="tictable" border="1">
<tr id="row1">
<td><button id="button1" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button2" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button3" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
</tr> 
<tr >
<td><button id="button4" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button5" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button6" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3">
<td><button id="button7" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button8" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
<td><button id="button9" type="button" onclick="actionPerformed(this)">&nbsp;</button></td>
</tr>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function actionPerformed(domObj)
    {
        domObj.innerHTML = "X";
    }

    </script>
```

i just copied this into a jsfiddle and it worked

Comment: When you pass in the dom object there is no need to get it again by using getElementById.

Comment: true true. nice catch.